# How to calculate the climb performance of an A320

Tags: airbus-a320, performance-calculation, climb

Recently I have been taking off in Innsbruck (LOWI) with my A320 (in Microsoft Flight Simulator, because I cannot afford the real one) and quickly found myself greeted by a GPWS Warning: "Terrain ahead!". I have been flying the MOGTI 3H SID from Runway 26. The charts state a required minimum climb gradient of 11.0% (that is 2233 ft/min at 200 kts). I probably should have calculated the climb performance before taking off, but I don't know how to do that.

Are there any tables on the climb performance of an A320 with a given weight, flaps and slats config, engines etc.? I didn't find anything specific on the internet. Or is there a way to make the MCDU show me that?

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for but for sim purposes it might do. https://contentzone.eurocontrol.int/aircraftperformance/details.aspx?ICAO=A320

Answer (score 1):

Most airlines have the NavBlue FlySmart software on a pilot tablet to calculate performance.

A rough way to calculate this is to use the MCDU. Convert your ft/min climb requirement to ft/nm.

$$ \frac{200 \, \text{kt}}{60 \, \text{min/h}} \approx 3.33 \, \text{NM/min} $$

$$ \frac{2233 \, \text{ft/min}}{3.33 \, \text{NM/min}} \approx 670 \, \text{ft/NM}$$

Check you first calculated waypoint crossing altitude on you MCDU to see if you comply.